# Find the $\frac{dy}{dx}$ for $x= \cos^{-1} \left(8t^4 - 8t^2 +1\right)$, $y= \sin^{-1} \left(3t-4t^3\right)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ where 
$$
x= \cos^{-1} \left(8t^4 - 8t^2 +1\right),\\ 
y= \sin^{-1} \left(3t-4t^3\right)
$$
For $0 < t < 1/2$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{\sin x}{\cos y}\frac{3-12t^2}{32t^3-16t}
$$
I will leave the rest to do.

The key thing is when you have something like this
$$
y = f^{-1}(g(t)) 
$$
where $f^{-1}$ is a simple function, then it is much easier  to compute this
$$
f(y) = g(t)
$$ 
and take derivatives and the invert again.

$$
\sin x = \sqrt{1-\cos^2 x}\\
\cos y = \sqrt{1-\sin^2y}
$$
using the above we can express the $\sin x, \cos y$ in terms of $t$.

Now for $\frac{dy}{dx}$ to be finite we require
$$
\cos y = \sqrt{1- \left(3t-4t^3\right)^2}\neq 0 \implies 1- \left(3t-4t^3\right)^2\neq 0\\
32t^3-16t = 32t\left(t^2-\frac{1}{2}\right)\neq 0
$$
For the first condition the cubic equation for each sign leads to only one root namely for $\pm 1$ we have $t = \mp 1$putting it all together we can only have two domains 
$$
0 < t < \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} < t < 0.
$$ 
which does not map to your original problem. which was $0 < t < 1/2$

Comment: What is the use of For 0<t<1/2 in this question. also can we get the dy/dx in terms of t

Comment: can you please help here

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

The formulas
$$\cos(4\alpha)=8\cos^4\alpha-8\cos^2\alpha+1,\qquad \sin(3\beta)=3\sin\beta-\sin^3\beta$$
help to detect the simple dependency between the variables $x$ and $y$ in this problem.